# md-gridlist in angular material design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am new to material design. I was implementing a grid list using angular material design. I am trying to understand the concept of grid list.

Can someone explain me the concept of angular material grid list?

Comment: Is there a particular area that you're having trouble with? There's no answer describing the entire concept that would be better than just reading the docs https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.gridList/directive/mdGridList

Comment: Thank you...i will refer that..i was going through another material